# Spatially Joining two tables

Tags: polygon, sql, spatial-join, mariadb

I have two tables in MariaDB. I am trying to join these two tables (Table 1 and Table 2). Table 1 contains `Longitude` and `Latitude` columns and Table 2 contains a `MultiPolygonGeom` column, which contains MultiPolygon types. I'm trying to join these tables based on if a row, in Table 1, contains a Longitude and Latitude that falls within the MultiPolygon of Table2. Table 1 has 10,000 rows and Table 2 has 138 rows (meaning 138 MultiPolygons).

Since the following code worked perfectly when I was working with regular Polygons, I tried the following:

```
SELECT table1.locCode,
table2.`Field A`, table2.`Field B`
FROM `database1`.`Table 2` table2
RIGHT JOIN `database1`.`Table 1` table1
ON ST_WITHIN(POINT(table1.`longitude`, table1.`latitude`), table2.`MultiPolygonGeom`)
WHERE table1.`locCode` != "TEST"
AND table1.`siteStatus` = 'ACTIVE'
```

As soon as I execute this code, the query keeps loading and doesn't stop. I have to manually stop the query from running since it doesn't stop for excessive periods of time. I'm not sure why it's taking so long since I only have 10,000 rows. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

---

Additionally, the engine is InnoDB and when I try to add the following SQL code:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_2` ADD SPATIAL INDEX(g);
```

I get an error message saying: InnoDB does not support spatial indexes

The result of my explain statement is as follows:

[image: Explain Statement]

Comment: Do you have a spatial index? https://mariadb.com/kb/en/spatial-index/

Comment: @Mapperz I don't have spatial indices currently in my database but I can add them into my database. Would you be able to tell how spatial indexes will help?

Comment: 'A spatial index is a data structure that allows for accessing a spatial object efficiently. It is a common technique used by spatial databases. Without indexing, any search for a feature would require a "sequential scan" of every record in the database,

Comment: @Mapperz thank you, that means if I add ```ALTER TABLE `Table 2` ADD SPATIAL INDEX(g);``` it would work?

Comment: please add the output of `EXPLAIN`

Comment: @IanTurton sorry for the late reply, but I did add the Explain statement in my question now